# <div> appears under cursor in textArea when I press ctrlKey?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the textBox(textArea) when I type something in it an then press ctrlKey I need some little 'div' appears under cursor. How can I manage that??

Comment: under **mouse cursor** or under **caret** that's within a texbox/textarea?

Comment: under caret thet is in textArea.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think those things can help you:

```
$('#yourTextAreaID').keypress(function(e) {
   // 17 is the keyCode for crtl
   if(e.keyCode == 17) {
     $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       $('#yourDiv').postion(e.pageX, e.pageY).show;
      }); 
   }

});
```

First It checks if the crtl key was pressed bey de keypress event trigger on your text area. Then it gets the current mouse postion on the screen, then its sets your div to the postion of the mouse

Comment: thanks, but I not need to involve any mouse work. First I type, then I press ctrl and div-block appears. Any mouse event contain pageX, pageY attributes and simple to show div were mouse cursor stand (mouse can be anywhere at this moment) when I press ctrlKey, but I try to manage that div appears exactly under cursor (caret) position in textArea and mouse can be anywhere.